# access grandparent class on class overwrites in magento, from a sibling

Tags: php, oop, magento, magento-1.9

It is required to overwrite customer_resource class. I added required config.xml options for resource rewriting, but when overwritten class method calls parent class method from itself, it actually called the parent method from which I extend to, nor the parent of Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer:

```
  class My_Plugin_Model_Resource_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer 
    {

    protected function _beforeSave(Varien_Object $customer){
        parent::_beforeSave($customer);
    ...
        }
    }
```

So, how to call parent method correctly in this case ? some kind of double downcasting is possible in php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution, in particular this case, was to call:

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave($customer);
```

as the required parent of Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer is Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract it will call the grandparent.

also, there is method with ReflectionMethod->invoke()

more info here: [How to call grandparent method without getting E_STRICT error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850802/how-to-call-grandparent-method-without-getting-e-strict-error)