# PHP class extension - skipping the middle class by calling the parent of the parent

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, prestashop

I'm currently trying to extend a Webshop CMS and am running into a problem. I have the following classes :

```
class a {
    public function doStuff(){
        // doing some A stuff
        return $something;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public function doStuff(){
        // doing some B Stuff
        $something = parent::doStuff();
        return $something;
    }
}

class c extends b {
    public function doStuff(){
        // doing some C stuff
        $something = parent::doStuff(); // <= problem here
        return $something;
    }
}
```

I can't change class a or b because they are core classes of the cms (prestashop), which is why all my code goes into class c.

I need `doing some A stuff`, without running *`doing some B stuff`* from class b. 
    I can't extend `a` directly because there's other code in `b` that I need.

I can't seem to come up with a clean solution to this problem other than just copy/pasting everything from `a->doStuff()` and not calling `parent::doStuff()` at all.

As far as I know, there's no parent::parent:: construct or anything similar. 
Does anyone know of a better solution without having to copy/paste everything?

Comment: Are all the methods called the same? In your example you called everything `doStuff()`, but are they named the same in your real classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call grandparent method without getting E\_STRICT error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850802/how-to-call-grandparent-method-without-getting-e-strict-error)

Comment: You have to explicitly call the method, for example: `CmsController::initContent` -> call `FrontController::initContent`, because you dont want to call `parent::initContent`, which is `CmsControllerCore::initContent`. We do it all the time. Yes it was confusing for me too at first. It's also dangerous sometimes when making override, you forget that calling `parent::method` may duplicate the code you're overriding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class c extends b {
    public function doStuff(){
        // doing some C stuff
        $something = a::doStuff(); // change here parent to 'a'
        return $something;
    }
}
```

I've done testing with this code and it works

```
<?php
class a {
    public function doStuff(){
        echo 'A-Stuff<pre>';
        return $something;
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public function doStuff(){
        echo 'B-Stuff<pre>';
        parent::doStuff();
    }
}

class c extends b {
    public function doStuff(){
        // doing some C stuff
        a::doStuff();
        echo 'C-Stuff<pre>';
    }
}

$c = new c;
$c->doStuff();
```

this echoes

```
A-Stuff
C-Stuff
```